# "Best" way to target specific hosts. Using inventory groups or `when` statements inside tasks?

Tags: ansible

I use Ansible at home to manager my 15 servers. I currently have 27 playbooks and 24 roles. I'm trying to combine things because this is too many playbooks/roles to manage.

Every playbook has `hosts: all` and I use `--limit` when running the playbooks in order to target specific hosts. I'd like to stop doing this (because if I forget `--limit` I could accidentally install Postgres on every machine inside `all`).

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  remote_user: ansible
  roles:
   - install_db_postgres
```

Is it best to:

1. Create dozens of groups in my inventory file, then update the playbooks to target that group? For example, my server `db05` runs Postgres, so it could be part of the `postgres` group in the inventory, but it also needs Certbot installed, so I'd have to also put it in the `certbot` group. It's also a virtual machine, so it would have to be part of the `vm` group. That's 3 groups for a single server...

or

2. Combine a bunch of roles into one then use `when: ansible_hostname == 'hostname_goes_here'` inside the task to target specific hosts? This would mean hard-coding the hostname into the task though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both, but for different purposes. And definitely don't have all your playbooks targetting "all".

So, you'll want a group `db_servers` and another `certbot_servers` and put `db05` in both of them. Playbooks might only target a single group or might have several sections targeting different groups. Depends on the purpose of the playbook. Create as many groups as you like - they don't cost you anything.

Typically all my servers are members of at least two groups - one based on their physical location (london_network, paris_network, new_york_network) and one on their main purpose (db_servers, web_servers). Most are probably members of the `monitored` group too and a few will be `mail_server`.

You can have sub-groups easily enough, say `db_primaries` and `db_secondaries` groups for replication but you might want to model this as host flags/variables. One replication group could only have a single primary for all its secondaries. So perhaps it makes more sense for you to have `london_replication` and for that group set `primary_hostname = 'db01'` and then do `when ansible_hostname == primary_hostname` (or its negative) to control certain tasks/configurations.

Comment: How many groups do you have? I'm thinking I'm going to have at least a dozen or more. Is that normal?

Comment: Yeah - that's fine. So long as your groups have a clear meaning and clean boundary have as many as you like.

Comment: @LoganM. I have inventories with hundreds of groups per environments accross DCs. And that can be thousands when you have dynamic inventories. Don't worry about the number but as pointed out by Richard, make sure those are meaningful and you know what you target exactly.